# How to find defined sequence in the list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sequence

For example I have list with events:

```
list = ['A','B','A','A','B','B','A'...]
```

I need to find sequence of events for example `'B','A','A'` to check if its exists or not If yes - how many times it's present in list.

For current list output should be:

```
Exists: 1 times
```

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: hmm.. an efficient way could be to create a sorted suffix array of your list. Then you will have all the suffixs (sublists or slices) that start with your sequence in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['A','B','A','A','B','B','A']
>>> pat = re.compile(r'BAA')
>>> sequences = pat.findall(''.join(l))
>>> sequences
['BAA']
>>> len(sequences)
1
>>>
```

But the best way to do this is using a generator function:

```
>>> def find_sequences(sequences, events):
...     i = 0
...     events_len = len(events)
...     sequences_len = len(sequences)
...     while i < sequences_len:
...             if sequences[i:i+events_len] == events: 
...                 yield True
...             i = i + 1
... 
>>> list(find_sequences(lst, events))
>>> sum(find_sequences(['AB', 'A', 'BA', 'A', 'BA'], ['A', 'BA']))
2
```

Answer (score 2):

As an exercise of looping and list slicing:

```
events = ['A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A']
target = ['B', 'A', 'A']

size = len(target)
count = 0
for start in range(len(events) - size + 1):
    if events[start:start + size] == target:
        count += 1
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
events = ['A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A']
target = ['B', 'A', 'A']

size = len(target)
count = len([start for start in range(len(events) - size + 1) 
             if events[start:start + size] == target])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sorted suffix array and binary search:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

# returns insertion index
def binary_search(seq, el, lo=0, hi=None):
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(seq)
    pos = bisect_left(seq, el, lo, hi)
    return pos

def subSequenceCount(sequence, subSequence):
    suffixes = []
    for start in range(len(sequence)-1):
        suffixes.append(sequence[start:])
    suffixes.sort()
    insertPos = binary_search(suffixes, subSequence)
    count = 0
    while insertPos < len(suffixes) and suffixes[insertPos][:len(subSequence)] == subSequence:
        count += 1
        insertPos += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a way to turn you list into string, you can use `str.count`:

```
lst = ['A','B','A','A','B','B','A']

to_str = ''.join

print "Exists: %d times" % to_str(lst).count(to_str(['B','A','A']))
```